# spectrum of complete p-partite graphs

Tags: graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory

I need to determine the spectrum of the complete p-partite graph ( in which each partite set has m vertices) using the complement. How can i show this?

I know the spectrum of the adjacency matrix of the complement is given by J-I-A(G) where J is the matrix of ones, I is the identity and A(G) is the adjacency matrix of G. How can I continue?

Comment: Well,  what *is* the complement? (I don't mean what is the definition, I mean can you describe it as a graph)?

Comment: it would be p paths, each on m vertices right?

Comment: No...try drawing it for say, $m=2$ and $p=5$.

Comment: sorryy i was wrong. I would be p complete graphs on m vertices

Answer (score 2):

*Things to keep in mind:*

1. The complement of a $p$-partite graph with every part having $m$ vertices is a disjoint union of $p$ copies of $K_m$.
2. The spectrum of a graph is the union of the spectra of its connected components.
3. The spectrum of $K_m$ is $m-1$ (multiplicity $1$) and $-1$ (multiplicity $m-1$).
4. If $H$ is a $k$-regular graph on $n$ vertices with spectrum $k\geq  \lambda_2\geq \cdots\geq \lambda_n$, then the spectrum of the complement $\overline{H}$ is $n-k-1 \geq -1-\lambda_n \geq\cdots \geq -1-\lambda_2$

Comment: then that mean that the complement of each complete graph has spectrum -1( with multiplicity 1) and 0 (with multiplicity m-1). there are p such complements therefore the overall complement would have -1 with multiplicity p and 0 with multiplicity p(m-1)?

Comment: Well you want the complement not of each individual complete graph, but the complement of all of them together. So the spectrum of the disjoint union of $p$ copies of $K_m$ is $m-1$ (with multiplicity $p$) and $-1$ (with multiplicity $p(m-1)$). Now apply (4) to that.

Comment: ok thanks a lot for your help